# Openframeworks_ofxcv-blob Tracking

Tags: opencv, openframeworks

I want to ask about use ofxcv in openframeworks.

I am using ofxcv’s ofxCv::ContourFinder to identify and track blobs. I would like to ask as shown above
There are two Blobs, ID 25 and ID 26.
After trying several times, I found that the merge of ofxcv will use the remaining object ID as the new ID after the merge. That is, if ID 25 is merged close to ID 26, the merged object ID will be 26.
Otherwise it is 25
I would like to ask if it can be modified to use a smaller ID as the new merged ID.

If you have any suggestions you can give me I will test the modifications. Thanks!